# Как отрезать слово до запятой? 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, строки

Есть строка типа:

```
CN=БУЛАТОВА ЖАНАР,SURNAME=БУЛАТОВА,SERIALNUMBER=IIN589658742568,
C=KZ,L=АЛМАТЫ,S=АЛМАТЫ ОБЛЫСЫ,O="ҚАЛА ШАРУАШЫЛЫҒЫ БАСҚАРМАСЫ" МЕМЛЕКЕТТІК МЕКЕМЕСІ,OU=BIN963258786458,G=БЕРІКҚЫЗЫ,E=zhanar_93@MAIL.RU
```

Нужно искать слово `CN` или (`S, L, CITY, SERIALNUMBER`). Если есть такое слово, то сразу отрезать это слово до запятой, то есть `SERIALNUMBER=IIN589658742568`
Как можно сделать это попроще на одной или не более двух строк?

Comment: А вы внимательно посмотрели ответ на тот вопрос в котором используется match ? вы посмотрели что вообще тот match возвращает ? Это от [1] там то что в круглых скобках, значит в скобки можно заключить все, что вам надо. кроме того если взять [0] то там полное совпадение - как раз то, что вы спрашиваете тут

Answer (score 2):

Все эти 3 метода делают то, что тебе нужно. Выбирай любой.

```js
let str = 'CN=БУЛАТОВА ЖАНАР,SURNAME=БУЛАТОВА,SERIALNUMBER=IIN589658742568, C=KZ,L=АЛМАТЫ,S=АЛМАТЫ ОБЛЫСЫ,O="ҚАЛА ШАРУАШЫЛЫҒЫ БАСҚАРМАСЫ" МЕМЛЕКЕТТІК МЕКЕМЕСІ,OU=BIN963258786458,G=БЕРІКҚЫЗЫ,E=zhanar_93@MAIL.RU';

console.log(str.split(",")[0]);
console.log(str.replace(/,.*/g, ""));
console.log(str.match(/(.*?),/)[1]);
```